# I can't paint on my meshes? I need help setting up texture paint on the Image Editor/ 3D Viewport

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view, texture-painting

So i'm creating a kitchen scene in blender 2.8. It's my first scene that i'm going to fully texture, give materials, give proper lighting, etc., and i can't seem to figure out how to set up texture paint. I painted some other meshes with texture paint, but I can't figure out what i did that isn't allowing me to paint, even though I'm in texture paint mode. If someone could help me out, that'd be great.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've opened a completely black *Texture Mask* so you can't paint anything, just close it.

[image]